# ASP .NET CORE - value displayed in my view is delayed by one step from the valid cookie value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, cookies

When I click on "Buy" button then the Buy method is executed. The cookie(key: article id, value: article quantity) is created in real-time and its value is always proper. But the problem is that  this line from Buy.cshtml @HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[(cart.ArticleId).ToString()] presents quantity of article in my shopping cart one action before the proper one.

**Example**

I click "Buy" button first time, the cookie(value=1) is created and there is no article displayed in my shopping cart, when I click "Buy" one more on the same product, the cookie value is 2 (valid) and now article is displayed in my shopping cart with amount 1. When I substract the quantity of article in my shopping cart, the cookie value is 1, but the quantity displayed in my shopping cart is 2 - so the quantity displayed in my shopping cart is always one step before.

**Buy method from ShoppingCart controller:**

```
public ActionResult Buy(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            if (Request.Cookies[id.ToString()] == null)
            {
                SetCookie(id.ToString(), 1.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                string newValue = (Int32.Parse(Request.Cookies[id.ToString()]) + 1).ToString();
                
                SetCookie(id.ToString(), newValue);
            }

            var myDbContext = _context.Articles.Include(a => a.Category);
           
            return View("Buy", myDbContext);
        }
```

**Buy.cshtml:**

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json
@Model Shop.Controllers.ShoppingCartController

@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

 @{
    List<Article> articles = new List<Article>();
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        foreach (var cookie in HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies)
        {
            if((cookie.Key).Equals((item.ArticleId).ToString()))
            {
                articles.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Koszyk";
}

    <h1>Koszyk</h1>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Nazwa
            </th>
            <th>
                Cena
            </th>
            <th>
                Kategoria
            </th>
            <th>
                Zdjęcie
            </th>
             <th>
                Ilość
            </th>
             <th>
                Łączna cena
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach (var cart in articles)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelCart => cart.ArticleName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelCart => cart.ArticlePrice)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelCart => cart.Category.CategoryName)
            </td>
             <td>
                <img src="@(cart.Image)" width="70px" height = "70px"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <td>
                @HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[(cart.ArticleId).ToString()]
            </td>
            <td>
                @{String.Format("{0:N0}", cart.ArticlePrice * Int32.Parse((HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[(cart.ArticleId).ToString()])));}
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Add" asp-route-id="@cart.ArticleId">+</a> |
                <a asp-action="Substract" asp-route-id="@cart.ArticleId">-</a> |
                <a asp-controller="ShoppingCart" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@cart.ArticleId">Usuń</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
<tr>
        <td colspan="5">Razem:</td>
        <td>
               
                   @{ var total = String.Format("{0:N0}", articles.Sum(x => x.ArticlePrice * Int32.Parse(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[(x.ArticleId).ToString()])));}
                
                @total 
        </td>
    </tr>
    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You're looking at the request cookie in your view, not the updated cookie. Suggestion: stop using the cookie itself in the Raxor code and use a view model instead.

Comment: @Llama I have to use mvc model. So do you have any other idea or conception?

Comment: View models are an essential part of MVC. It simply says: Do not access "everything" from your view but collect the relevant data in a view model (which is simply a class). You can use the ViewBag too.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen So I have to pass from my controller to view: list of all articles and cookies stored in my browser. How do oyu recommend me to pass them? And I wonder, because I have methods like AddQuantityArticleCart, RemoveArticleFormCart, SubstractQuantityArticleCart and I do not know if I should use one view for all the methods.

Comment: Look at your view and extract what data your view needs in a class. This might be the articles and their amount. Now in your controller action, fill the data - if the amount is stored in cookies, fill it from the cookie values. In most cases you'd use the same view for all actions because the view part will be the same.

Comment: Btw.: If you store the cart articles in cookies, you may want to modify this value in javascript without reloading the page after each click.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen this is possible but I have no clue how to do this :)

Comment: @ChristophLütjen What about creating a list of articles that are in shopping cart (including quantity from cookies) and passing it to my view?

Comment: "What about creating a list of articles..." this is what @Llama and I suggested. We call it a view model.